# Backbone - binding to a collection's reset event loses reference to `this`

Tags: scope, backbone.js, coffeescript

I don't think this is an uncommon problem, but I haven't been able to make any of the solutions I've found work. Here's my [simplified] view:

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View
    el: '#mydiv'

    initialize: ->
        @collection.bind 'reset', @render, @

    render: ->
        $(@el).html('my content')
```

When `reset` is triggered, `render`'s `this` has been clobbered, and `@el` is `undefined`. My understanding was that the 3rd parameter on `bind` was supposed to take care of this, but that doesn't appear to be happening. I am using Backbone 0.5.3.

I also tried using the "fat arrow" on render, but that didn't work either:

```
    render: =>
        $(@el).html('my content')
```

**Update**

As Trevor Burnham pointed out below, it wasn't a scoping issue, it was that my `el` property wasn't available at page load (it get's created later). I'm still looking for a better way to deal with that (using the `id` property on the view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem is that `render` is called in the wrong context, but rather that the view's `el` property is never a DOM element. Does something with the ID `mydiv` exist at the time that you call `new MyView`? If not, that's the problem.

Internally, when `el` is a string, Backbone makes the call

```
this.el = $(this.el).get(0);
```

from the view's constructor. If nothing matching that selector string exists, `@el` will be `undefined`, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: Yup, that's what I discovered... The tag with the `el` id won't be created until something else happens, so it will always be undefined. Is there a better way to do that then? I've taken to using the `id` property instead, but will that have unforeseen problems down the road?

Comment: Typically, you should just delay instantiation of the view until the element it represents exists. If `#mydiv` is part of your page, then all you have to do is wrap `new MyView` in `$` to make it run after the DOM is ready: `$ -> myViewInstance = new MyView`. If you're removing and adding the element dynamically, you should delete and re-instantiate `MyView` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the double arrow `=>` instead of single-arrow `->` when defining your `render` method, and CoffeeScript makes sure that the `this` pointer points to the class instance. Also, you may want to try to set the `id` member to the id reference instead of the `el` member, as the documentation for backbone (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el) indicates that `el` gets created (by backbone itself) based on whatever `id`, `tagName` and `className` is set to.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Updated my question to reflect that.